# Html.EditorFor, data annotations and html attributes for DateTime field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor, data-annotations, html

I want to use EditorFor for a DateTime field, because then I can use data annotations to describe the format (I do not want to include the time part). I also want to assign an html class attribute (class="date").
When I use EditorFor helper function, I cannot assign html attributes.
When I use EditorFor and I create editor template, I can specify the class in the template, but then I lose the formatting. This is how my DateTime editor template looks like:

```
@ModelType DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model, New With {.class = "date"})
```

How do I make this work, so the data annotations are taken into account and so I can add the class attribute? The annotations that I talk about are:

```
<Display(Name:="Task start date")>
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
<DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the DataAnnotations flow through, you must change your Editor Template to use `TextBoxFor` instead of `TextBox`, like so:

```
@ModelType DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m, New With {.class = "date"})
```